# How to email multiple users for a lookup column which references contacts list with the user's email?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am trying to email users in my task list where Assigned To is a lookup column that references contacts list with AD users and external vendors(not in AD). When i try to email the users using workflows , if Assigned To has a  one name it works fine. But if it has more than 1 name then the users are separated by semicolon or commas depending if i return the field as string, or values comma delimited and the workflow will not send emails to the multiple users.

Is there a way for me to email multiple users if it is a lookup column and not "person or group" column? Maybe separating the names in the lookup column and emailing them individually?

Comment: Any limits for emails count?

Comment: @AlexZh Hopefully as many as possible, but probably less than 5

Comment: I'd edited answer with new code. Hope it helps. It works on my test SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `emailto` is your lookup.

1. Add text field `resultemails` and yes/no field `IsNeedToReplace`.
2. In your workflow:

   - `resultemails` = `emailto` (as values comma delim)
   - `IsNeedToReplace` = `Yes`
   - Wait intil `resultemails` does not contains `','`
   - Email to `resultemails`
3. Write powershell script and scheduled it to start every minute.

Use following code to replace value:

```
        $spSite=Get-SPSite -Identity "http:\\yoursitecol";
        $spWeb=$spSite.OpenWeb();
        $spList = $spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("listname");
        if ($spList)
        {
            $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
            #$spQuery.ViewAttributes = 'Scope="Recursive"';
            $spQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='IsNeedToReplace'/><Value Type='Text'>1</Value></Eq></Where>";            
            $spListItems = $spList.GetItems($spQuery);

            if ($spListItems.Count -gt 0)
            {
                foreach($spItem in $spListItems)
                {
                    $spItem["resultemails"] = $spItem["resultemails"] -replace ",", ";";
                    $spItem["IsNeedToReplace"] = 0;
                    $spItem.SystemUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
        $spSite.Dispose();
```